# Issue in uploading Image on webserver using JSON

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-fragments, image-uploading

I am trying tp upload an image from my application, the webservice is working perfectly as i have tried to upload the image using POSTMAN Client. I tried to search over in the stackoverflow, but no luck yet. If someone can help me with the same. Thanks in advance.

> > FragmentTab1.java

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment  {

Button postAd, browse;
EditText discription;
EditText price;
String discriptionText;
String priceText;
String adTypetext;
RadioGroup adType;
RadioButton buy;
RadioButton sell;
Bitmap bitmap;
ProgressDialog dialog;
String encodedImage;
String userid;
JSONArray AdsArray = null;
String TAG_ID = "id";
String TAG_IMAGE = "image";
String TAG_TYPE = "adType";
String TAG_DISCRIPTION = "description";
String TAG_PRICE = "price";
String TAG_COUNTER = "counter";
ListView lv;
Switch myswitch;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
final Context context = getActivity();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> adList;

private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("onCreateView", "entry1");
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);
  getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
    }

    postAd = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bpostAd);
    discription = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etDiscription);
    price = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etPrice);

    browse = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.bBrowse);

    lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("IDvalue", 0);
    userid = mPrefs.getString("userIdKey", null);
    adList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    new LoadMyAds().execute();



    discription.addTextChangedListener(txwatcher);

    postAd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            discriptionText = discription.getText().toString();
            priceText = price.getText().toString();
            if (encodedImage == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                new ImageUploadTask().execute();

                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.postAd(encodedImage,
                        discriptionText, adTypetext, priceText, userid);
                try {
                    if (json.getString("status") != null) {
                        String res = json.getString("status");
                        if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Ad has been posted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "posting error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });

    browse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {

                Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setType("image/*"); 
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    });

  return rootView;
  }





@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("onActivity Result", "Image");

    switch (requestCode) {
    case PICK_IMAGE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String filePath = null;

            try {
                // OI FILE Manager
                String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                // MEDIA GALLERY
                String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                    filePath = selectedImagePath;
                } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                    filePath = filemanagerstring;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
                }

                if (filePath != null) {
                    decodeFile(filePath);
                } else {
                    bitmap = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Internal error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }

        }
        break;
    default:
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Log.e("getPath", "entry3");

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
        // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else
        return null;
}

public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
    // Decode image size
    Log.e("decodeFile", "entry4");

    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);



    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
    Log.e("Decodefile", "bitmap set");
}

class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("ImageUpload", "entry5");                  
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
        // encodedImage = new String(data);
        encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);             
        return  encodedImage;
    }
}
public  boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
    }
 }
```

> > Userfunction.java

```
public class UserFunctions {
     private JSONParser jsonParser;

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }
            public JSONObject postAd(String encodedImage, String discriptionText,
            String adTypetext, String priceText, String userid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", encodedImage));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", discriptionText));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("adType", adTypetext));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", priceText));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", userid));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(postAdUrl, "POST", params);
            return json;
    }
}
```

> > Output

The first json output is been posted using POSTMAN client and there image get successfully uploaded so webservices is working perfect I guess.
The second result shows the image link without any extension using above code so I guess I'm doing something wrong in my code.

```
{
        "id": "5",
        "image": "http://iphoneappsdevelopment.info/kwebservices/upload/ads/ACK0_YNVY_IKLF.jpg",
        "adType": "Buying",
        "description": "hskskg",
        "price": "100",
        "counter": "1",
        "adUserId": "9"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "image": "http://iphoneappsdevelopment.info/kwebservices/upload/ads/YBR7_3VOG_9ZJN.",
        "adType": "Selling",
        "description": "sjsj",
        "price": "1088",
        "counter": "2",
        "adUserId": "9"
    },
```